# Django 1.7 - Adding permissions programmatically does not work as expected

Tags: django, permissions, django-1.7

What is going on here ?

```
> from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
> from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
> p = Permission.objects.filter(
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Transaction)
).get(
    codename = 'add_transaction'
)
> user.user_permissions.add(p)

> user.user_permissions.all()
[<Permission: myapp | Transaction | Can add Transaction>]
> user.get_all_permissions()
set([])
> user.has_perm('add_transaction')
False
> user.has_perm('myapp.add_transaction')
False
```

am i missing a save here somewhere ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ModelBackend` caches the permissions on the user object.  The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching) suggest that you reload the user from the db after changing the permissions.

```
user.user_permissions.add(p)
user = User.objects.get(pk=user.pk)
```

Comment: I hope we can use `user.refresh_from_db()` now.

Comment: No, `refresh_from_db` will not clear the cache. It is mentioned in the comment in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#permission-caching)

Comment: Added extra model permission not getting reflected on the test db. I managed to update the original db by python manage.py update permission but It shouldn't get reflected while I'm testing.. Does this answer will help in that situation?

Comment: No, that doesn't sound related to this question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

`dgel`'s answer is correct but incomplete. Both `_perm_cache` and `_user_perm_cache` need to be cleared to force a full reload.

```
for attr in ('_perm_cache', '_user_perm_cache'):
    delattr(user, attr)
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe user instances have a permissions cache that is populated when it is first pulled from the DB.  Try deleting the cache before calling `has_perm`:

```
delattr(user, '_perm_cache')
```

After that, `has_perm` should work as expected.  Normally this isn't an issue as you rarely add then immediately test for permissions on the same user instance (without pulling it from the DB again).  Definitely can trip you up when you're testing in the python shell though.

Comment: Wonder why django doesn't have a built in way of purging an object cache. This is a pretty commno use case (add the permission and perform the action ... ).